# Nagios: how to monitor supermicro based systems

Tags: nagios

I have several older supermicro based NAS devices. Happened to be at our hosting facility today and saw that one had a disk failure. I thought that I was monitoring this via SNMP->Nagios but clearly I'm missing something crucial.

Suggestions on how best to track the status of these sorts of machines? For my Dell servers I use OpenManage and Nagios. It seems to do a good job of telling me when disks have failed, memory isn't happy, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nagios plugins to monitor the server via IPMI. Also, Supermicro has it's own monitoring software called SuperDoctor, which also relies on IPMI.

**More Details:**

http://exchange.nagios.org/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=search&Itemid=74&searchword=ipmi

http://www.supermicro.com/products/nfo/SMS_SD3.cfm

ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/utility/SuperDoctor_II/Linux/

Comment: Looks like SuperDoctor doesn't do anything with disks. This must be from the RAID controller instead.